# How to limit the number of options in a select?

Tags: html, reactjs, select, tailwind-css

I am working on a project using React and tailwind.

I would like to filter the options I mean I want see to at most 3 options. I tried `slice` but it is not a solution because using `slice` for instance if I type `a` I want to see at most 3 words which contains the letter `a` if I type `b` I want to see at most 3 words which contains the letter `b` and that words for a and b can be different so `slice` cannot be a solution.

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select, { components} from "react-select";
import { useState } from "react";

let cheeses = ["Wagasi", "Kalari", "Halloumi", "Manouri"];

let options = [];
options = options.concat(cheeses.map((x) => "Cheese - " + x));

const Foo = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function MakeOption(x) {
    if (value) {
      return { value: x, label: x };
    } else {
      return { value: "", label: "" };
    }
  }

  const handleInputChange = (value, e) => {
    if (e.action === "input-change") {
      setValue(value);
    }
  };

  const Input = props => <components.Input {...props} maxLength={5} />;

  return (
    <Select
      isMulti
      name="colors"
      options={options.map((x) => MakeOption(x)).filter(opt => opt.value !== "")}
      className="basic-multi-select"
      classNamePrefix="select"
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      inputValue={value}
      noOptionsMessage={() => null}
    />
  );
};

export default Foo;
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code works like you want.

The problem have been solved with a second variable for the select options.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select, { components} from "react-select";
import { useState } from "react";

let cheeses = ["Wagasi", "Kalari", "Halloumi", "Manouri"];

let options = [];
options = options.concat(cheeses.map((x) => "Cheese - " + x));

const Foo = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [optionsToShow, setOptionsToShow] = useState([]);

  function MakeOption(x) {
    return { value: x, label: x };
  }

  const handleInputChange = (value, e) => {
    if (e.action === "input-change") {
      setValue(value);
      const nextOptions = value ? options.map((x) => MakeOption(x)).filter((opt) => opt.label.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) : [];
      setOptionsToShow(nextOptions.length > 3 ? nextOptions.splice(1,3) : nextOptions);
    }
  };

  const Input = props => <components.Input {...props} maxLength={5} />;

  return (
    <Select
      isMulti
      name="colors"
      options={optionsToShow}
      className="basic-multi-select"
      classNamePrefix="select"
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      inputValue={value}
      noOptionsMessage={() => null}
    />
  );
}
export default Foo;
```

I hope I've helped you